# Journey builder history status: ContactPreviouslyInSameInteraction

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have problems with users who enter the journey, but have a journey status of: ContactPreviouslyInSameInteraction. For me it doesn't ring a bell, because the user only enters the journey but won't go through any of the activities in the journey. The journey history I've attached.

The journey entry source is a Data Extension. the contacts Evaluation = The journey evaluates all records. I think there lies the problem, but the user would enter at least once all the activities I would say. [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"ContactPreviouslyInSameInteraction" means the contact is already in the journey and re-entry is not permitted. However, once they exit the Journey, they could enter again if they are still in the Data Extension.

Since ‘Evaluate new records only’ is set to ‘FALSE’, all records in the data extension will be evaluated. If this was set to ‘TRUE’, only new records in the data extension would be evaluated each time for entry the journey, and you will avoid injecting the same contact multiple times.

Please refer to the following documentation for more details:

[Manage Entry Source Data](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_manage_audience_data.htm&type=5)

I would recommend you to change the "Evaluate New Records Only" to true, so the same records aren't evaluated each time, and only new records in the DE are evaluated for entry.